# Finding The Free Variables In A linear Equations System

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the free variable of the following linear equations system
>
> \begin{cases} x + 2y + -3z=2 \\ 2x – 3y + z = 1\\ 5x  -4y  -z=4\end{cases}

Now the book says that because the system is not row reduced there is not free variables.

So I row reduced it to

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -3 & 2 \\
    0 & -7 & 7 & -3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Now the system of course has no solution (As once I read, because there is a pivot element in the b column).

will it be write to say that there is a free variable namely $z$ or because there is not solution there isn't any?

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? As the RREF, I get $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -1 & \dfrac{8}{7} \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & \dfrac{3}{7} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Moo sorry, typo

Comment: Updated RREF - looks like you made a slight error because our second rows match. This system does have a free variable, namely $z$.

Comment: @Moo Why do you say it is $z$? I can write $$y= x-\frac{5}{7};\;z= x-\frac{8}{7}$$

Comment: @Raffaele: My comment is based on the typical convention of solving using bottoms-up because that makes calculations easier. I have no issue with your observation, I am just following convention.